# In C, I want to access one array in two separate processes

Tags: c, multithreading, fork, public

This is essentially what I want to do, but the outputs are junk data. What are some of the different options I have for making the child's array visible from inside the parent process?

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int foo[3];                                     //initialize array

    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();                                   //create child thread

    if (pid == 0) {                                 //child:
        foo[0] = 0; foo[1] = 1; foo[2] = 2;         //populate array
    }

    else {                                          //parent:
        wait(NULL);                                 //wait for child to finish
        printf("%d %d %d", foo[0], foo[1], foo[2]); //print contents of array
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No no no. You ***DO NOT*** want to do this.

Comment: `fork` doesn't create a separate thread, it creates a separate process. The child process is modifying *its* copy of `foo` (linux implements copy-on-write memory when forking). If you really want to use multiple threads, look up pthreads.

Comment: Access away lol. Child and parent have their own copies. You get junk data because parent never bothered to write anything to it's array

Comment: Yeah, I realized on my own that I said "threads" when I'm actually forking processes here. What I had intended to ask was the same question but in regards to threads.
Even so, why is this wrong to do?

Comment: Aside from it being fundamentally flawed (see Stephen Newell's comment) you usually want to coordinate a locking mechanism to avoid memory corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) you can create a shared memory block in your parent process.  This is a basic example removing error checking for brevity.

You want to sure the proper protections and flags are set for your needs.  Then hand off the address returned by `mmap` to your child process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LIMIT_MAP 5

void child_worker(void *map)
{
    int map_value = -1;
    int idx = 0;

    while (map_value != LIMIT_MAP) {
        map_value = *((int *) map + (idx * sizeof(int)));
        printf("Map value: %d\n", map_value);
        idx++;
        sleep(2);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Starting Parent Process...\n");

    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);

    void *memory_map = mmap(0, page_size, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, 
                                          MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);

    printf("Memory map created: <%p>\n", memory_map);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("Starting child process\n");
        child_worker(memory_map);
        printf("Exiting child process...\n");
        return 0;

    } else {

        printf("Continuing in parent process\n");

        int set_values[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            printf("Setting value: %d\n", set_values[i]);
            *((int *) memory_map + (sizeof(int) * i)) = set_values[i];
            sleep(1);
        }

        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

        printf("Child process is finished!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If `fork` isn't a requirement and your platform allows for it, `pthread` is one option.  Depending on how your array is being operated on, create a thread pool passing each worker thread a copy of your array.

This is a contrived example but maybe you can pull something from it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define THREAD_COUNT 3
#define ITER_LIMIT   7

struct worker_params {
    int idx;
    int max;
    bool done;
    double *data;
    double condition;
};

void *worker(void *arg)
{
    struct worker_params *wp = (struct worker_params *) arg;

    int count = 0;

    while ( 1 ) {

        wp->data[wp->idx] = drand48();
        if (wp->max == count)
            wp->done = true;
        sleep(1);

        count++;
    } 

    return NULL;   
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double data[THREAD_COUNT] = { 0.0 };

    pthread_t worker_1, worker_2, worker_3;
    pthread_t worker_threads[] = { worker_1, worker_2, worker_3 };

    struct worker_params wps[] = {
        { .idx=0, .condition=0.1, .data=data, .done=0 },
        { .idx=1, .condition=0.2, .data=data, .done=0 },
        { .idx=2, .condition=0.3, .data=data, .done=0},
    };

    for (int i=0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
        wps[i].max = (rand() % ITER_LIMIT) + 2;
        pthread_create(&worker_threads[i], NULL, worker, (void *) &wps[i]);
    }

    // Continue on main execution thread

    int running = 1;

    while ( running ) {
        for (int i=0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
            if (wps[i].done) {
                printf("Limit hit in worker <%d>\n", i + 1);
                running = 0;
                break;
            }

            printf("Data in worker <%d> :: %g\n", i + 1, wps[i].data[i]);
        }

        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```